# How to check that screen lock has a password?

Tags: android

I'm currently checking if there is a screen lock password  with:

DevicePolicyManager.getgetPasswordMinimumLength() != 0

so if I see that the length is 0 I conclude there is no screen lock password and I prompt user to set one with `DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD`.

I wonder though if it's a correct method of checking whether a screen lock password has been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DevicePolicyManager.isActivePasswordSufficient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isActivePasswordSufficient%28%29) to check whether your password policy is sufficient instead of getPasswordMinimumlength

Comment: But if I don't have any password still isActivePasswordSufficient returns true.

Comment: You need to call DevicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality and DevicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength before calling this function. Only then will the framework return whether the present password conforms to the quality